# Android devices discovery with DHCP

Tags: android, udp, dhcp

I went through the questions here about Android devices auto-discovery, the best results I do have is while monitoring UDP port 67, I can see message types 'discovery' and 'request' data that can be used to pretty reliably detect Android devices. But I would like to detect also already connected devices.

Is there a way how to ask unknown device on UDP port 68 for information about itself (like pretending I am the DHCP server) ? The only message types I found DHCP server ever can sent to devices are

DHCPOFFER, DHCPACK, DHCPNAK

So far I did not have any success to get responses from the devices and also I do not want to ruin the obtained IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking the android device you could obtain information about a specific device from the DHCP server. The RFC 2131 protocol spec includes the DHCPINFORM message. It says “Servers receiving a DHCPINFORM message construct a DHCPACK message with any local configuration parameters appropriate for the client without: allocating a new address …“. When you know the device IP address, the you can send a DHCPINFORM request to the DHCP server and get in return everything that the server knows about the device without ruining anything.